# Django req.POST always returns False

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, webhooks, ngrok

I am testing a shipstation webhook and I can't seem to get data from the POST request they are sending.

Their webhook [docs](https://help.shipstation.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003180331-Using-ShipStation-Webhooks) say that their POST request will contain a body that looks like this:

```
{"resource_url":"https://ssapiX.shipstation.com/orders?storeID=123456&importBatch=1ab23c4d-12ab-1abc-a1bc-a12b12cdabcd","resource_type":"ORDER_NOTIFY"}
```

To debug the issue, I went into the Firefox and tried to send this:
[image: Firefox POST request]

And got the same result; `req.method = 'POST'` and `req.POST = False`

View controller for `myNgrokAddress.ngrok.io/bot/shipstation`:

```
@csrf_exempt
def vc(req):
    print(req.META) //this works but it looks like meta-data for my browser and not from shipstation
    print(req.POST.get('resource_url')) //prints false
    print(req.POST) //prints false


    return HttpResponse('')
```

When I go to `localhost:4040` (the ngrok inspector) the POST body shows up, so something must be incorrectly configured on my django server.

I set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myNgrokAdress.ngrok.io', 'localhost']` in my settings.py.  Is there something else I need to do?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is it something to do with peculiarities in HTTPS requests perhaps? Just spitballing

Comment: That's correct, the `req.POST` are the POST *headers* in the request, not the content of the request.

Comment: To be more specific, in cases where ive done this, I recall needing to have a certificate to present to the server

Comment: @Willem I think you are incorrect, as the django request docs say that `req.POST` returns a queryDict object from the request.  That being said you made me realize that the data type wasn't a queryDict, and I should just use `req.body` xD Thanks

Comment: @Jane: that was exactly what I meant: it simply takes the *headers* from the request, not the body. Of course Django turns it into an object. Where do I state otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `req.POST` method.

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/) :

> HttpRequest.POST:
>
> A dictionary-like object containing all given HTTP POST parameters, providing that the request contains form data. See the QueryDict documentation below. If you need to access raw or non-form data posted in the request, access this through the **HttpRequest.body** attribute instead.

Since the data-type being sent is *non-form* data, you will need to use `req.body` instead.